# NIC not working on Ubuntu server with GUI

Tags: networking, server

I am trying to set up Ubuntu 18.04 server with a GUI.  It is an older computer and 20.04 doesn't seem to boot after install.  I am running server because I am using LVM raid.  I am going to running nextcloud, openVPN, and a media server, not sure what yet, on this machine.  I currently have nextcloud and open VPN running on a much older machine.  I can get 18.04 installed, updated, but after I install a GUI I can use the NIC, there is none listed.  I a have tried KDE plasma and tried Ubuntu budgie from tasksel.  I believe Ubuntu cloud image is taking the NIC and the GUI can't access it.  During boot I see flying by some IP addresses.  I recorded it with my phone and the IP shows under Ubuntu cloud image.  I tried removing Ubuntu cloud in tasksel and it wouldn't boot anymore.  Any ideas how to get the NIC to work with a GUI on server?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo service NetworkManager status | grep Active` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-08-29 01:42:58 UTC; 3min 40s ago

Comment: #This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network: ethernets: eno1: dhcp4: true version: 2

Comment: So, the internet is working but the network GUI shows no networks

Answer (score 1):

When you installed the server addition, networking was handled by netplan. You have posted the relevant netplan file.

When you later installed a desktop environment, or GUI, Network Manager was installed along with all of its configuration files. NM and netplan are in disagreement as to who is responsible for networking. Let’s put NM in charge. From the terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/netplan/*.yaml
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation, spacing, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x followed by Enter).

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.